# Why first() method doesn't throw no sequence exception in the following query

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

```
var aaa = _dbContext.IdentityAppUsers
    .Where(x => x.Uuid == 'ABC')
    .SelectMany(l => l.OrganisationOrganisationUsers)
    .Select(x => 
      x.Organisation!.OrganisationStandards
      .Select(od => od.Uuid).First());
```

As OrganisationStandards is an empty collection, I expected the above query will throw an no sequence exception on the method First(), but it doesn't.

Any thoughts?

The generated sql is like

```
SELECT (
    SELECT o1.uuid
    FROM query.organisation_standard AS o1
    WHERE o0.id = o1.organisation_id
    LIMIT 1)
FROM query.identity_app_user AS i
INNER JOIN query.organisation_organisation_user AS o ON i.id = o.user_id
INNER JOIN query.organisation_organisation AS o0 ON o.organisation_id = o0.id
WHERE i.uuid = 'ABC'
```

Comment: So the select is never executed because there is nothing so the call to first inside the select is also never executed?

Comment: well, you never *execute* that query somewhere. You'd need to iterate `aaa` in order to execute the statement and eventually throw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `x.Organisation!.OrganisationStandards.Select(od => od.Uuid).First()` is not actually a C# call and as you clearly can see is translated into SQL. It should actually throw if `od.Uuid` would be a non-nullable value type (though it would be completely other exception - `System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.`).

EF tries to translate queries to SQL as closely as possible to .NET behavior but it is not always possible, or sometimes is to cumbersome or have to much edge cases. In this one for example if `od.Uuid` would be an nullable string it would be a more complex query to write to determine if returned `null` represents actual null value from database or a missing row.